my code with cvxpy.Variable is not work,and the error say "Invalid dimensions (5,) for Variable value."
my code is :
import cvxpy as cp

# 创建整数变量 x，取值范围为 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
x_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x = cp.Variable(integer=True, value=x_values)

# 构建目标函数和约束条件（示例：最小化 x 的和）
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum(x))
constraints = [cp.sum(x) == 1000]  # 假设 x 的和为 1000

# 构建并求解问题
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
prob.solve()

# 输出结果
print("最小的 x 的和:", prob.value)
print("x 的取值:", x.value)

the output is :
ValueError: Invalid dimensions (5,) for Variable value.

all output is：
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 5
      3 # 创建整数变量 x，取值范围为 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
      4 x_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
----> 5 x = cp.Variable(integer=True, value=x_values)
      7 # 构建目标函数和约束条件（示例：最小化 x 的和）
      8 objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum(x))

File e:\app\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\cvxpy\expressions\variable.py:88, in Variable.__init__(self, shape, name, var_id, **kwargs)
     86 self.delta = None
     87 self.gradient = None
---> 88 super(Variable, self).__init__(shape, **kwargs)

File e:\app\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\cvxpy\expressions\leaf.py:151, in Leaf.__init__(self, shape, value, nonneg, nonpos, complex, imag, symmetric, diag, PSD, NSD, hermitian, boolean, integer, sparsity, pos, neg)
    147     raise ValueError("Cannot set more than one special attribute in %s."
    148                      % self.__class__.__name__)
    150 if value is not None:
--> 151     self.value = value
    153 self.args = []

File e:\app\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\cvxpy\expressions\leaf.py:370, in Leaf.value(self, val)
    368 @value.setter
    369 def value(self, val) -> None:
--> 370     self.save_value(self._validate_value(val))
...
    397     )
    398 projection = self.project(val)
    399 # ^ might be a numpy array, or sparse scipy matrix.

ValueError: Invalid dimensions (5,) for Variable value.


You forgot the dimension in the declaration of x: x = cp.Variable(5, integer=True, value=x_values)
